# C++ How to read input N and then read a series of numbers N long?

Tags: c++, string, vector, segmentation-fault, getline

I'm working on an assignment where I need to create a program that reads a non-empty sequence of integer numbers, and tells how many of them are equal to the last one.

It should read the amount of integers the sequence has and then read the sequence itself and return the amount of times the last number repeats itself excluding the last one.

Input would be like this:

```
9
1 7 3 2 4 7 5 8 7
```

and the output should be:

```
2
```

Now, I have no problem with the functionality of the program but I'm struggling on having it read the inputs. This is what I got:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

int NumbersEqualToLast(int limit, std::vector<int> elements) {
  int check = elements[limit], counter = 0;
  for (int i = limit; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (elements[i] == check) {
      counter++;
    }
  }
  return(counter);
}

int main() {
  int amount, number;
  std::cin >> amount;

  std::string input;
  getline(std::cin, input);
  std::stringstream iss(input);
  std::vector<int> numbers;
  while ( iss >> number ) {
    numbers.push_back( number );
  }
  std::cout << NumbersEqualToLast(amount, numbers) << std::endl;
}
```

The problem is after reading the amount of integers (in this case 9) I get a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error.

EDIT AFTER SOLUTION

This is what worked for me using your suggestions. Thank you.
I understand if it's not pretty or there are better more efficient ways but I'm just starting out. :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int NumbersEqualToLast(int limit, std::vector<int> elements) {
  int check = elements[limit - 1], counter = 0;
  for (int i = limit - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (elements[i] == check) {
      counter++;
    }
  }
  return(counter);
}

int main() {
  int quantity;
  std::cin >> quantity;
  int number;
  std::vector<int> numbers;
  for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
    std::cin>>number;
    numbers.push_back(number);
  }
  std::cout << NumbersEqualToLast(quantity, numbers) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Always post a [mcve] as required here please, no matter of you think the code you left out is irrelevant.

Comment: Your question is about how to read N values in a loop.  Your problem describes something that happens _after_ the loop (most likely in the function that you didn't show).  To address the question in your title, you stop reading values when the vector reaches that size.  And after the loop, you should ensure that you _did_ actually read enough values.  As good practice, you should reserve storage before pushing a known quantity of data onto a vector: _e.g._ `numbers.reserve(amount);`

Comment: Now that you've updated the question, we can see `elements[limit]` is out of bounds.  The last element is at index `limit - 1`.  Or you can use `elements.back()`.  As an aside, get in the habit of passing vectors by reference into functions instead of copying them.

Comment: In the real world this would be done with [`std::count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count).

Comment: `std::count(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), numbers.back()) - 1;` -- Stop writing loops and learn the algorithm functions.  Basically a  one line solution.

Comment: buffer overflow in NumbersEqualToLast https://godbolt.org/z/nqd9a4jqa

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/r8rb4hTh8

Comment: The bottom line is that algorithm functions such as `std::count` will never "core dump" if you give them the proper iterators and arguments to the function.  Hand writing `for` loops as you've done will be error-prone, as you are seeing now.

Comment: I understand there are better and more efficient ways to do this but this type of answer is what the person evaluating me is looking for sadly. And even with your propositions the problem still is that I'm not even able to input the numbers I need to check. As soon as I enter N (which is 9 in this case) I get the segmentation fault error and i can't input the list so I don't see how the way my function works affects that if it wont even reach the call to it. I'm still learning so i'm sorry for my ignorance in these matters or if I'm not explaining myself correctly. I still appreciate the help.

Comment: @Medose *but this type of answer is what the person evaluating me is looking for* -- You should state this up front, what is allowed and not allowed.  Otherwise, you potentially waste time with volunteers who would have posted the simple `std::count` answer,  Second, and as an earlier comment mentioned, the problem is not in the reading of the numbers.  It is that your function to figure out the count is incorrect.  I see that you accepted an answer that is very convoluted, IMO.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie To your first point I completely understand. This is my first post on here so I'll be sure to take that into account in any future posts I might make. As to your second point I agree the function in the solution I accepted is convoluted and I'm not even 100% sure what they're doing in it. But like i showed in the last edit of the post, I used the way they took the input and changed what I had with it leaving my function nearly intact and the code finally worked as intended for that example I showed and with others of similar nature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just don't judge harshly, please**. I suggest another way to solve this problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int special, count;
void dfs(int current, int previous, vector<int>& visited, vector<int>& input)
{
    if(visited[current]==1)
    {
        return;
    }
    visited[current]=1;
    if(current==(input.size()-1))
    {
        special=input[current];
    }
    for(int next=(current+1); next<input.size(); ++next)
    {
        if(next==previous)
        {
            continue;
        }
        dfs(next, current, visited, input);
    }
    if(special==input[current])
    {
        ++count;
    }
    if(current==0)
    {
        --count;
        cout<<count;
    }
    return;
}
void solve()
{
    int quantity;
    cin>>quantity;
    int number;
    vector<int> numbers;
    for(int i=0; i<quantity; ++i)
    {
        cin>>number;
        numbers.push_back(number);
    }
    vector<int> visited(quantity);
    dfs(0, -1, visited, numbers);
    return;
}
int main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
9
1 7 3 2 4 7 5 8 7
```

Here is the result:

```
2
```

Comment: dfs? Did you by mistake post answer under wrong question?

Comment: @Marek R, Respected Marek, I have tried to return the amount of times the last number repeats itself excluding the last one.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/r8rb4hTh8

Comment: @Marek R, Respected Marek, your solution is more shortly than mine. You are right.

Comment: I used the way you input the sequence into the vector and now my program works. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this solution looks more like a [Rube Goldberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine) implementation of something that should be very simple.  You're doing depth first search on something as simple as getting the last element and counting?